# Multiple of an Integer inside range

Tags: java

I am doing a school project and I kinda got blocked.
I am looking forward building a javascript that asks the user of a number between 1 and 20 and then finds and lists all the multiples of that number inside range 0 and 100.

Here is what it looks like at the moment:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("*** Program start ***\n");
    System.out.println("Insert number [integer, between 1 and 20]: ");
    boolean okay = false;

    while (!okay) {
        int n1 = lector.nextInt();
        lector.nextLine();
        if (n1<1 || n1>20) {
            System.out.print("Invalid number!\nplease try again [between 1 and 20]: ");
        } else {
            okay = true;
            System.out.println("Number accepted!");
        }

    int i = 0;
    while (i <= 100) {
       System.out.println(i);

       if ((n1%100) == 0) {
           System.out.println(n1);
       }
       i = i + 1;
    }
    System.out.println("\n*** End ***");
    }
    }
}
```

I am obviously bad at math cause I can't get the formula to work.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Javascript ? Java, surely ?

Comment: starting from the number, if you multiply it by 2,3,4,5,... you will get all multiples

Comment: So why not just add your initial number to itself repeatedly, and report that, until that value exceeds 100 ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking about some math formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All multiples that fall between 0 and 100? That's the kind of thing for-loops are made for. After performing your IO and reading the number `n1`, change that while loop to the following.

```java
for (int i = n1; i >= 0 && i <= 100; i = i + n1) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

In case you aren't familiar with for loops, this basically says, set `i` to the value of `n1`, and keep adding `n1` to it, printing each value as you go. When it leaves the range of 0..100, it terminates. So for instance, if 8 is entered it goes 8, 16, 24, 32, ..., 80, 88, 96.

If you really want to use a while loop, then try:

```java
int i = n1;
while(i >= 0 && i <= 100) {
    System.out.println(i);
    i = i + n1;
}
```

Comment: That's what I was looking to get! But can it be done with a while instead of for? It asks me for a while condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("*** Program start ***\n");
    System.out.println("Insert number [integer, between 1 and 20]: ");
    boolean okay = false;

    while (!okay) {
        int n1 = lector.nextInt();
        lector.nextLine();
        if (n1<1 || n1>20) {
            System.out.print("Invalid number!\nplease try again [between 1 and 20]: ");
        } else {
            okay = true;
            System.out.println("Number accepted!");
        }

    int i = 0;
    while (i <= 100) {
       System.out.println(i);

       if ((n1%i) == 0) {
           System.out.println(i);
       }
       i = i + 1;
    }
    System.out.println("\n*** End ***");
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: don't you think `while (i*n1 <= 100)` would be more efficient?

Comment: Actually I haven't checked that I just shooted the answer.

Comment: But... this finds factors, not multiples.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("*** Program start ***\n");
    System.out.println("Insert number [integer, between 1 and 20]: ");
    boolean okay = false;

    while (!okay) {
        int n1 = lector.nextInt();
        lector.nextLine();
        if (n1<1 || n1>20) {
            System.out.print("Invalid number!\nplease try again [between 1 and 20]: ");
        } else {
            okay = true;
            System.out.println("Number accepted!");
        }

    int i = 0;
    while (i <= 100) {
       System.out.println(i);

       if ((n1*i) <= 100) {
           System.out.println(i);
       }
       i = i + 1;
    }
    System.out.println("\n*** End ***");
    }
    }
}
```

This should work. You were just finding if the number `n1` was divisible by 100.